# Jest: Explicit Promises Work Differently From Async Test

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, jestjs, jasmine

It seems like the following tests should have the same result:

```js
import {render, act} from '@testing-library/react';

test('async test', async () => {
    let component;
    await act(()=>{
        component = render(<div/>);
    });
    console.log("logging");
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});

test('without callback', () => {
    let component;
    act(()=>{
        component = render(<div/>);
    }).then(()=>{
        console.log("logging");
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

with the following `package.json`:

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "react-scripts test --verbose",
        "check": "jest --version"
    }
}
```

The first test succeeds as expected (and I can see its output), but the second test outputs `Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?`.

Why is jest surprised by the logging done in the promise continuation in the second test but not the second test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example: there is no way jest to know that it should wait.

If you do not use async/await - you have to return a promise in the test function so that jest knows its a promise and it will wait until the promise is resolved/rejected or timeout has expired.

So code should look like this:

```js
test('without callback', () => {
    let component;
    return act(()=>{
        component = render(<div/>);
    }).then(()=>{
        console.log("logging");
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#promises